How to modify dynamically loaded <style> tags
I have a Vue ^2.7.15 application running on Vite ^4.5.0. When I run a dev server, <style> tags of each component are added into the <head> element, for example:
<style type="text/css" data-vite-dev-id="/src/components/MyButton.vue?vue&type=style&index=-100&scoped=fc7ab1b1&lang.scss"">
/* CSS rules */
</style>

I would like to transform this tag before it gets appended to the DOM. How can I achieve this?
I have tried writing a vite plugin, however nothing different happens:
export default function myPlugin() {
  return {
    name: 'myPlugin',
    enforce: 'post',
    install() {
      if (isDevMode) {
        const originalAppendChild = document.head.appendChild;

        document.head.appendChild = function (element) {
          if (element.tagName === 'STYLE') {
            element.setAttribute('test-attribute', 'test-value');
          }
          return originalAppendChild.call(document.head, element);
        };
      }
    },
    transform(code, id) {
      if (!/vue&type=style/.test(id)) return;
      return {
        code: code.replace(
          /(<style)/g,
          '$1 <style test-attribute="test-value">'
        ),
        map: null
      };
    }
  };
}

Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you.

What are you trying to achieve with this whole thing?

I need to put these tags into a shadow dom element elsewhere in the document. This is because I am integrating a Vue app into another one and would like to have their styles properly encapsulated.
